# LongListSelector with horizontal Scrolling - WP8

Tags: xaml, scroll, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

Is there any way to make LongListSelector scroll horizontally?

By Default its scrolling vertically. There is no ItemPanel property or ScrollViwer available to change the orientation.

Any help will be greatly appreciated:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewport control that replaces the scrollviewer can scroll horizontally.
You can modify the ManipulationLockMode of the ViewPortControl in the LLS template.

But I don't think the LongListSelector is made to scroll horizontally.

What part of the LLS do you need that you can't replace by the good old listbox + horizontal virtualizingstackpanel combo ?

Answer (score -1):

Longlist selector tag in side   use following :    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"

Comment: That does not change the scroll mode only the scrollbar visibility for a LongListSelector.